# Adding An ArrayList To Another ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am currently studying for the *Java Programmer 1 certificate* and the following piece of code came up about adding an ArrayList to another.

```
ArrayList<String> myArrList = new ArrayList<String>();
            myArrList.add("One");
            myArrList.add("Two");
            ArrayList<String> yourArrList = new ArrayList<String>();
            yourArrList.add("Three");
            yourArrList.add("Four");
            myArrList.addAll(1, yourArrList); 
            for (String val : myArrList)
             System.out.println(val);
```

This is what the author then says:

> What happens if you modify the common object references in these
>   lists, myArrList and yourArrList? We have two cases here:
>
> In the first one, you reassign the object reference using either of the lists. In
>   this case, the value in the second list will remain unchanged.
>
> In the second case, you modify the internals of any of the common list
>   elements,in this case, the change will be reflected in both of the
>   lists.

What is the author trying to say?? I am a bit confused about the 2 cases he mentions!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't figure it out either. Strings are immutable anyway, so their internal state can not be changed.

Comment: @JBNizet: This part definitely handles about ArrayLists and not strings. Strings are used as an easy content-filler in this demo.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: *you modify the internals of any of the common list elements*: the elements of the lists are Strings, and he talks about modifying their internals. Can you explain what the author means?

Comment: Yep you were right, sorry on that one. I guess this is a excerpt out of its context, or either a bad book :p

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I think it could be the latter, very confusing :) It was a section on ArrayLists and this part came up. I was mainly wondering if I modify the contents of _yourArrList_ after the for loop, will the modified content be updated in _myArrList_ ??

Comment: @GaryFox no, it won't. You should be able to test that easily.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the author is trying to say. But Strings are a bad example to do it with. Imagine something like this. He is explaining the difference between adding two different instances of a class to the lists, or adding the same instance to both lists. When you add the same instance to both lists, if you modify that instance the change is reflected in both lists.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Example {

    private static class Node {
        private int value;

        public Node(final int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(final int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final ArrayList<Node> nodes1 = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<Node> nodes2 = new ArrayList<>();

        // add two different Node objects that happen to have same value
        nodes1.add(new Node(1337));
        nodes2.add(new Node(1337));

        Node node = new Node(69);

        // add the same node to both lists
        nodes1.add(node);
        nodes2.add(node);

        node.setValue(420);

        // do your join here and print result to see {1337, 420, 1337, 420}
        nodes1.addAll(0, nodes2);
        for (final Node n : nodes1)
            System.out.println(n.getValue());
    }

}
```

Comment: Cheers that clears alot up, you are right Strings was a bad example!